# tar only those folders listed in a file

Tags: linux, bash, find

Here is my problem

the directory structure is

```
/home/user/backup/name1/date1/name1-date1.cfg
/home/user/backup/name1/date2/name1-date2.cfg
/home/user/backup/name2/date1/name2-date1.cfg
/home/user/backup/name2/date2/name2-date2.cfg
/home/user/backup/name3/date1/name3-date1.cfg
/home/user/backup/name3/date2/name3-date2.cfg
```

and so forth

I have a .txt file which lists

```
name1
name2
```

now what I need to do is to read the .txt file and create a tar file of the folders name1 and name2 only. I am not sure if it could be done with a single find command or a script but either will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
tar cvf mytarfile.tar -T names.txt
```

Here we have:
`c` Create a new archive
`v` Verbose output so we know what is happening
`f` The archive file should have name...
`T` Read the list of files from...

You just would need to be in the `backup` directory.

Comment: Thanks ... works perfectly for my requirement

Comment: Note that this does **not** with with `tar` but only with `gtar`. Real `tar` implementations use the option `-I`.